# Terminal vs Eclipse PosixFilePermissions

Tags: java, filesystems, posix

By running the same command from the Eclipse and from the command line I get 2 different results:

With Eclipse everything works fine, however with the command line I get the following error message:

```
PosixThing.java:17: error: error while writing PosixThing: PosixThing.class (Permission denied)
```

This error message does not appear if I run "**sudo** javac PosixThing.java".
As it if was not strange enough, the same code with a different file located in the same directory (Desktop) does not give me any problem. (I am talking about mere txt files just to test the PosixFilePermissions function).

I checked the file permissions and everything is -rw -rw -rw As well as the others'. Do not know why it happens only with that specific file.
Running on Ubuntu 11.10 jdk 1.7.

Any suggestion to what it might be?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a file / filesystem permissions problem of some kind:

- Check the owner, group and permissions for the file, and all directories on the file pathname.
- Check that you are running Eclipse and your command shell as the same effective user.
- Check that you are not attempting to write to some kind of "funky" file system; e.g. a Windows file system mounted on Linux, or a FUSE file system of some kind.
- If you've got SELinux enabled, check that's not causing the problem.  (That's unlikely.)

It is also possible that you are running different releases / versions of Java in the two contexts, or even that Eclipse's file system cache is out of sync.  (It is not clear to me what contexts the code is actually running in.)